# How to omit devDependencies when copying node_modules?

Tags: gulp

I'd like to copy only modules, which are important for application - those located inside `dependencies` in `package.json`. I'd like to omit those under `devDependencies`.

`package.json`

```
{            
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "^4.13.4",
        "log4js": "^0.6.33"            
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "gulp": "^3.9.1",
        "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
        "gulp-typescript": "^2.12.1",
        "typings": "^0.7.9",
        "yargs": "^4.3.2"
    }
}
```

`gulpfile.js`

```
gulp.task('copy_packages', function() {
      gulp
         .src('node_modules/**/*.*')
         .pipe(gulp.dest('../release/node_modules'));
});
```

Is there any module or a  smart way to distinguish which modules belongs to `dependencies` group and which to `devDependencies`?

Comment: You will probably want to script some solution around `npm install --production` if you're interested in pulling dependencies as well.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem...felt weird this was not considered when gulp was created.
My work around was using child_process to run npm install and specify a directory to put the node_modules directory with only the packages you need for your application.

e.g:

`gulp.task('createDeployNodeModulesFolder', function(cb) {
    spawn('"npm"', ['install', '--prefix', './dist/', 'package1', 'package2'], {stdio: 'inherit', shell: true}, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stdout);
        console.log(stderr);
    })
    .on('close', cb);
});`

In your case you want only the production dependencies so you can likely use:
npm install --prefix /deployDir/ --only=prod

There will be some warnings complaining about no package.json..etc., but those are just warnings. If you really want to get rid of them, I guess you can just add a task to copy or create a package.json into the deploy directory before running npm install.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js allows you to `require()` JSON files which will be returned as simple JavaScript objects. You can use that to only pass those modules to `gulp.src()` that appear under `dependencies` in your `package.json` file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var packageJson = require('./package.json');

gulp.task('copy_packages', function() {
  var modules = Object.keys(packageJson.dependencies);
  var moduleFiles = modules.map(function(module) {
    return 'node_modules/' + module + '/**/*.*';
  });
  return gulp.src(moduleFiles, { base: 'node_modules' })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../release/node_modules'));
});
```

Comment: I expect problem with dependencies. If modul under 'dependencies' has dependency to 'moduleXYZ', it won't be attached.

Comment: Right, this doesn't account for transitive dependencies

Answer (score 0):

use distize https://www.npmjs.com/distize .

```sh
npx distize --no-files -o {targetpath}
```

Comment: no. this pkg is crap. I try to pass —src another node modules path, but it is install root lvl node modules. I can’t figure out how to stop it neither.